# getting error with execute many in python

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I am learning python and i am new bie.
I am trying to use functions with mysql and python and i ma getting errors

This is my script

```
import MySQLdb
def insert_values(cursor, values):
    #cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("""
        insert into pythontest (name1,name2,name3)
        values (%s, %s, %s)""", values)
    cursor.close()

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","python" )
cursor = db.cursor()

var1 = ['name1','name2','name3']
insert_values(cursor,var1)

db.close()
```

There may be many errors because i am learning

> 1)i don't know how can i pass db
>   object in function or passing cusrsor
>   is ok. because i have to call that
>   function many times in for loop
>
> 2)is the syntax of values array ok to
>   go in database

ERRORS

```
File "mysql.py", line 10, in insert_values
    values (%s, %s, %s)""", values)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 216, in executemany
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: Please, specify errors you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write that (But untested):

```
import MySQLdb

def insert_values(db, values):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        try:
            cursor.execute("""
            insert into pythontest (name1,name2,name3)
            values (%s, %s, %s)""", *values)
        except:
            db.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            db.commit()
    finally:
        cursor.close()

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","python" )

vars = ('name1','name2','name3')
insert_values(db, vars)

db.close()
```

The cursor starts a transaction, so you don't want to re-use the same cursor for multiple updates unless they are part of an atomic transaction.

Comment: i get this error TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (5 given) , also need to replace cursor.rollback with db.rollback

Comment: right, should have checked. But it looks like what you really want us just the execute method.

Comment: The execute method worked after removing "*" from values. But i want to know what do i need to do in my code to make executemany work. i am just learning stuff. EDIT: the executemany also worked  if i replace `vars = [('name11','name12','name13'),('name21','name22','name23')]` but if i put star(*) in *values then i get same error

Comment: Right, it wants a list of tuples to apply the SQL to, many times. Different signature.

Answer (score 2):

```
cursor.executemany("""
        insert into pythontest (name1,name2,name3)
        values (%s, %s, %s)""", *values)
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it is the correct answer. The OP was sending a list, `*values` unpacks the list into the 3 values that format string expects. The error message is very clear about the problem.